# Difference in RelativeLayout and other in onMeasure

Tags: android, layout

So, basically i have a custom view :

```
public class CustomView extends PercentFrameLayout
```

As you can see i've inherited it from `PercentFrameLayout`(might be the reason for this issue, but i'm not sure)

Inside of this view i've inflated layout .xml file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

<View
    style="@style/SomeStyle"
    app:layout_widthPercent="98%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="98%"/>
....
</merge>
```

Also, in this custom view, i've overriden `onMeasure` method to multiply it's size by 2(just for test):

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 2|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) * 2|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }
```

Currently this custom view is in RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <com.example.CustomView
              android:id="@+id/progress_new_collagen"
              android:layout_width="120dp"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***The issue:*** Currently, its size not multiplied by two, its multiplied by, like 4 for width and 3 for height, and i don't know why.

***The strange thing which made me want to ask a question:*** If it's not `RelativeLayout` as parent to this view, but any other `ViewGroup` class, like `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout` and so on - **code is working**. It's also working if i just remove `onMeasure`. Is there any difference in this ViewGroups in case of `onMeasure` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` will call `onMeasure()` twice each time it is rendered. I think that this is why you are getting your strange results. If the second `onMeasure()` uses the results from the first call, that you will not double, but quadruple your dimensions.

Comment: You actually right! Thank you, also, do you know anything to prevent it? It's just in real project there is a lot going on in this layout, and if i'll change it, from just RelativeLayout it would become at least 3 other =(

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent the double measuring pass of the `RelativeLayout` - it's just how it works. One thing you could try to do is try and be smart about when to change the measure specs. Maybe you can calculate your desired dimensions and only alter the specs if you haven't reached them yet.

Comment: yes, i have solved my issue by prederming returning size. So basically, RelativeLayout is just the combination of LinearLayout and FrameLayout and that's why it measure its children twice? One time for each layou used to create it?

Comment: I think it's related to the relative rules inside, it takes two phases to get all the measurements right. This talk could shed some light on the whole concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA